# CSS3 background transitions

Tags: css, transition

So I want to recreate exactly that ribbon transition http://subtlepatterns.com/ but I am doing smth wrong. My ribbon image is 140x160 [width,height] but by hovering nothing happens.

I put:

```
#toplogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    background-position: 0px -10px;
    z-index: 5000;
}


#toplogo a {
    background: url('ribbon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 140px;
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
    background-position: 0px -10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.10s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: 0.10s ease-in;
}



<div id="toplogo"> <a href="/">hello</a> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in CSS -

```
#toplogo a:hover{
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#toplogo a {
    background: url('ribbon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 140px;
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
    background-position: 0px -10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-position .1s ease-in;
}

#toplogo a:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```